# Added Clustering, saw huge memory increase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I added clustering to my node.js application and saw a huge increase in memory consumption. The average memory total in heroku went from about 70mb to 250mb.

Is this normal?

www bin

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var debug = require('debug')('temp:server');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // If a worker dies, log it to the console and start another worker.
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died.');
    cluster.fork();
  });

  // Log when a worker starts listening
  cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
    console.log('Worker started with PID ' + worker.process.pid + '.');
  });

} else {
  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
   */

  var server = http.createServer(app);

  /**
   * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
   */

  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
}

// The rest of the bin/www file.....

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: `cluster` starts new processes, and each such process is running the Node.js interpreter which in turn is running your "worker" code. It's like you're starting "numCPUs" separate instances of your app.

Comment: So, you're saying a significant memory increase is supposed to happen.

Comment: It's expected to happen, yes. Do you need to use `cluster` for a particular reason?

Comment: Scaling my website. Expecting a huge influx of visits soon.

Comment: Fair enough. Like I said, more processes means more memory usage.